# Converting an UIview unto UIimage causing memory leak

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiimage, coverflow

I'm developing an app for iPhone using a coverFlow view, when the app is building the cards it is using  a UIView in order to add labels and other stuff. Then I convert the UIView into UIImage using the following code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.bounds.size);
[imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// returning the UIImage
return viewImage;
```

Every Time I redraw the coverflow I have a huge memory allocation increment, that never decreases even if I dealloc my coverFlow view.

I think the memory leak is in the code that I added, what do you think?

Comment: I've experienced the same issue and opened a radar with Apple.  It was closed as a duplicate, so you are not alone.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Pls help me. How Can we solve this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no memory leak apparent in the code snippet you provided. That operation could not be performed on a background thread because of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()`, so you should have an `NSAutoreleasePool` in place (the return value of `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentContext()` is autoreleased). Without further information, its impossible to tell where the memory leak could be - I suggest you look at whatever objects eventually own the viewImage object and make sure you are properly releasing the UIImage if you retain it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:` instead of `renderInContext:` it is **15x faster**.

[image: Performance comparison]

You can see the comparison on [this article](http://damir.me/ios7-blurring-techniques).

Also, I have created a Swift extension for doing this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32042439/517707

Answer (score 0):

Those who are coming here to convert multiple **UIView** to **UIImage** but getting memory leak. **autoreleasepool** can solve this issue.
For example: To convert all subviews as UIImage

```
for subview in superView.subviews {
     autoreleasepool {
        let outputImage = subview.asImage()
     }
}


extension UIView {
    func asImage() -> UIImage? {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
            return renderer.image { rendererContext in
                layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
            }
        } else {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)
            self.layer.render(in:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
            guard let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else {
                return nil
            }
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else {
                return nil
            }
            return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
        }
    }
}
```