# Convert UIView to .png in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

How do I convert a UIView to an image. I found this [convert uiview to .png image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748669/convert-uiview-to-png-image) but I'm not to familiar with Objective-C. I took a stab at translating this to Swift but it didn't go so well. could any help?

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myView.frame.size);
[myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData *data=UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewImage);
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *strPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myimage.png"];
[data writeToFile:strPath atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(myView.layer.frame.size, false, scale)
myView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
let viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewImage)
let documentsDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
let writePath = documentsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("myimage.png")
data.writeToFile(writePath, atomically:true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5 version:

```swift
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(myView.layer.frame.size, false, 1) // 1 = scale
myView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
let viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
let documentsDir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
let writePath = documentsDir.appendingPathComponent("Image.png")
try! viewImage!.pngData()!.write(to: writePath)
print("Saved image to:" writePath)
```