# Image from Hidden UIView

Tags: swift, uiview

I am currently trying to get an image from a UIView, using this [Convert UIView to .png in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31020608/convert-uiview-to-png-in-swift)

It works when the view is present on the screen, however I was wondering if there is a way to get the view when it is hidden so that the user can't see the view but I can still process the content.