# WKWebView CALayer to image exports blank image

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, wkwebview

I'm trying to take a screenshot of webpage but the image is always blank(white).

I'm using this code to convert `CALayer` to `Data`[(taken from here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41387514/4859791)

```
extension CALayer {

/// Get `Data` representation of the layer.
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - fileType: The format of file. Defaults to PNG.
///   - properties: A dictionary that contains key-value pairs specifying image properties.
///
/// - Returns: `Data` for image.

func data(using fileType: NSBitmapImageFileType = .PNG, properties: [String : Any] = [:]) -> Data {
    let width = Int(bounds.width * self.contentsScale)
    let height = Int(bounds.height * self.contentsScale)
    let imageRepresentation = NSBitmapImageRep(bitmapDataPlanes: nil, pixelsWide: width, pixelsHigh: height, bitsPerSample: 8, samplesPerPixel: 4, hasAlpha: true, isPlanar: false, colorSpaceName: NSDeviceRGBColorSpace, bytesPerRow: 0, bitsPerPixel: 0)!
    imageRepresentation.size = bounds.size

    let context = NSGraphicsContext(bitmapImageRep: imageRepresentation)!

    render(in: context.cgContext)

    return imageRepresentation.representation(using: fileType, properties: properties)!
}

}
```

And then to write the data to file as `.png`

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) 
{
    let d = web.layer?.data() as NSData?  //web is the instance of WKWebView
    d!.write(toFile: "/Users/mac/Desktop/web.png", atomically: true)
}
```

But I'm getting a blank(white) png instead of what I expected

1). What am I doing wrong?

2). Is there any other possible ways to get the image representation of
    webpage(Using swift)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Latest Update:**

Now you can take screenshot of `WKWebView` just like `WebView`.

[Apple added new method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/2873260-takesnapshot?changes=latest_minor) for both iOS and macOS,

```
func takeSnapshot(with snapshotConfiguration: WKSnapshotConfiguration?, 
completionHandler: @escaping (NSImage?, Error?) -> Void)
```

But its still in beta.

---

You can't take a screenshot of `WKWebView`. It always returns a blank image. Even if you try to include `WKWebView` inside another `NSView` and take a screenshot, it will give you blank image in place of `WKWebView`.

You should use `WebView` instead of `WKWebView` for your purpose. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38191642/saving-webview-to-pdf-returns-blank-image?rq=1).

If you are ok with using private frameworks(apple doesn't allow your app in its store), check this [GitHub](https://github.com/lemonmojo/WKWebView-Screenshot). Its written in Obj-C. I don't know Obj-C so I can't explain what's happening in that code. But it claims to do the work.

Your best approach is to use `WebView` and use your mentioned extension `data()` on the `WebView`.

Just a question: Why don't you use phantomJS?

PS. Sorry for the late reply. I didn't see your e-mail.

Comment: Thanks! I saw about that question but I never saw that github repo but sadly I too don't know objc.

Answer (score 0):

Update: **Swift 5** adding to prior.

I didn't want controls in the output, so I bound a key sequence to it (local key monitor):

```
case [NSEvent.ModifierFlags.option, NSEvent.ModifierFlags.command]:
    guard let window = NSApp.keyWindow, let wvc = window.contentViewController as? WebViewController else {
        NSSound(named: "Sosumi")?.play()
        return true
    }
    wvc.snapshot(self)
    return true
```

and work within a sandbox environment. We keep a bunch of user settings in the defaults like where they want snapshots to be captured (~/Desktop), so 1st time around we ask/authenticate, cache it, and the app delegate on subsequent invocations will restore sandbox bookmark(s).

```
var webImageView = NSImageView.init()
var player: AVAudioPlayer?

@IBAction func snapshot(_ sender: Any) {
    webView.takeSnapshot(with: nil) {image, error in
        if let image = image {
            self.webImageView.image = image
        } else {
            print("Failed taking snapshot: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "--")")
            self.webImageView.image = nil
        }
    }
    guard let image = webImageView.image else { return }
    guard let tiffData = image.tiffRepresentation else { NSSound(named: "Sosumi")?.play(); return }

    //  1st around authenticate and cache sandbox data if needed
    if appDelegate.isSandboxed(), appDelegate.desktopData == nil {
        let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
        openPanel.message = "Authorize access to Desktop"
        openPanel.prompt = "Authorize"
        openPanel.canChooseFiles = false
        openPanel.canChooseDirectories = true
        openPanel.canCreateDirectories = false
        openPanel.directoryURL = appDelegate.getDesktopDirectory()
        openPanel.begin() { (result) -> Void in
            if (result == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK) {
                let desktop = openPanel.url!
                _ = self.appDelegate.storeBookmark(url: desktop, options: self.appDelegate.rwOptions)
                self.appDelegate.desktopData = self.appDelegate.bookmarks[desktop]
                UserSettings.SnapshotsURL.value = desktop.absoluteString
            }
        }
    }

    //  Form a filename: ~/"<app's name> View Shot <timestamp>"
    let dateFMT = DateFormatter()
    dateFMT.dateFormat = "yyyy-dd-MM"
    let timeFMT = DateFormatter()
    timeFMT.dateFormat = "h.mm.ss a"
    let now = Date()

    let path = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: UserSettings.SnapshotsURL.value).appendingPathComponent(
        String(format: "%@ View Shot %@ at %@.png", appDelegate.appName, dateFMT.string(from: now), timeFMT.string(from: now)))

    let bitmapImageRep = NSBitmapImageRep(data: tiffData)

    //  With sandbox clearance to the desktop...
    do
    {
        try bitmapImageRep?.representation(using: .png, properties: [:])?.write(to: path)

        // https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1913/_index.html
        if let asset = NSDataAsset(name:"Grab") {

            do {
                // Use NSDataAsset's data property to access the audio file stored in Sound.
                 player = try AVAudioPlayer(data:asset.data, fileTypeHint:"caf")
                // Play the above sound file.
                player?.play()
            } catch {
                Swift.print("no sound for you")
            }
        }
    } catch let error {
        NSApp.presentError(error)
        NSSound(named: "Sosumi")?.play()
    }
}
```