# How to use WKWebView in a command line app

Tags: swift, command-line, wkwebview

I'm trying to write a command line tool that takes a screenshot of a given webpage using WKWebView. The problem is that WKNavigationDelegate methods aren't being called. This is what I have:

```
import WebKit

class Main: NSObject {
    let webView: WKWebView = WKWebView()
    func load(request: URLRequest) {
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.load(request)
    }
}

extension Main: WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("Did start")
    }
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("Did commit")
    }
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("Did finish")
    }
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        print("Did fail")
    }
}

let main: Main = Main()
let input: String = CommandLine.arguments[1]
if let url: URL = URL(string: input) {
    let request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    main.load(request: request)
} else {
    print("Invalid URL")
}
```

Almost all examples I've found involve using WKWebView in a view controller. My guess is that in the command line, the app exits before the webpage finishes loading, but I'm not sure how to prevent that from happening.

I did find [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44618623/using-webview-in-command-line-found-nil-error-while-unwrapping) of a command line tool using WKWebView. The author uses RunLoop.main.run(), which to my understanding effectively simulates the event loop of a UI app? That allows the webpage to load, but I'm looking for a different solution because I want the app to behave like a normal command line tool and exit on its own after running. For example, is there some way to use async/await with WKWebView.load() much like with URLSession?

Comment: You can use something like that https://stackoverflow.com/a/28591237/1801544 The idea, is to indeed use the `RunLoop` , but also stops when the work is done. In the `webView(_:didFinish:)` or `webView(_:didFail:withError:)` changing the "stop condition".

Comment: @Larme thank you, I only saw this after figuring out how to do it with continuations as detailed in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75446788/17096282). This would also have worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem using `continuation`. In short, I wrap `webView.load()` in a `continuation` and then call `continuation.resume()` in one of the `WKNavigationDelegate` methods. That allows me to treat `webView.load()` as an async task; the continuation determines its runtime. I took this solution entirely from [the example in this blog post](https://www.artemnovichkov.com/blog/async-await-offline).

Here's a barebones implementation of this solution:

```
import WebKit

@MainActor
class WebContainer: NSObject {
    
    lazy var webView: WKWebView = {
        let webView: WKWebView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        return webView
    }()
        
    var continuation: UnsafeContinuation<Void, Error>?
    
    func load(request: URLRequest) async throws -> Int {
        try await withUnsafeThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            self.continuation = continuation
            webView.load(request)
        }
    }
}

extension WebContainer: WKNavigationDelegate {

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        continuation?.resume(returning: ())
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        continuation?.resume(throwing: error)
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        continuation?.resume(throwing: error)
    }
}
```

To load a website using the above implementation, simply run:

```
let webContainer: WebContainer = WebContainer()
let request: URLRequest = // insert URLRequest here
try await webContainer.load(request: request)
```

Practically speaking this implementation doesn't handle redirects reliably as some redirects are initiated after didFinish is called. I have a partial solution to that which however runs into other problems. Since all this is out of scope for this question, if anyone's interested please refer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75445808).