# Save edited image to the iPhone gallery

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiimageview, cglayer

am working on an app where i am loading one image from the bundle and with the help of quartz i am adding two red circles on that image, the image is loaded in the instance of the UIImageVIew class.

I want to save the image with the red circle, so far i have found only one method and thats

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage * image,id completionTarget,SEL completionSelector, void * contextInfo)
```

but its not working as it is saving the image from the bundle only, in some post i have read that it can be done using CALayer but i found no useful link to do that, i would be glad if you can post me the answer or any tutorial link to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trick! Refer to [**Capture UIView**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4334902/1603234) here, you can capture the `UIImageView` snapshot and save it using `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`.