# Rounded Rect / Rounded corners for images in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uiimage, calayer

I use this category and create images for my UITableView to all be the same size.  Is there a way to have the images have rounded corners as well?  Thanks!

```
+ (UIImage *)scale:(UIImage *)image toSize:(CGSize)size
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    UIImage *scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return scaledImage;
}
```

Edit: I then get the image, and other object info to put it in an NSDictionary to get in the UITableView.  I tried changing the UIImageView.layer property in the cellForRowAtIndexPath, but it doesn't seem to do the trick:

```
cell.TitleLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"Name"];
cell.CardImage.image = [dict objectForKey:@"Image"];
cell.CardImage.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add clipping to the drawing operation, the `UIBezierPath` class makes this super easy.

Extend you code to:

```
+ (UIImage *)scale:(UIImage *)image toSize:(CGSize)size
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundeRect:rect cornerRadius:5] addClip];
    [image drawInRect:rect];
    UIImage *scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return scaledImage;
}
```

Comment: fyi there's a missing 'd' in bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect.  I'd just edit the answer but there's a minimum 6 character change to edit something.  Just thought I'd point out in case someone else spends time trying to figure out why there's no known method "bezierPathWithRoundeRect:rect" and missed the typo :)

very nice answer though

Comment: This approach can lead to blurry corners on retina devices. This works very well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4334902/1022589

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
image.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Include QuartzCore framework.
2. Import CALayer.h
3. image.layer.cornerFRadius = 5;

Answer (score 0):

As said Sisu and the.evangelist : image.layer.cornerRadius = 5;

But you may need to also add :

[image.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];