# How to copy the rasterized content of a UIView into a new UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit

I have a complex `UIView` with lots of custom subviews, and I need to make a visual copy of it as a new `UIView` appearing with that rasterized content.

So far I do it by calling `renderInContext:` to get a new `UIImage`, but maybe you know a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using renderInContext: is Apple's recommended way to rasterize a view hierarchy. I believe it is the only way to do it in the SDK using Apple APIs.

Comment: NB Note Tommy's awesome answer on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334233/how-to-capture-uiview-to-uiimage-without-loss-of-quality-on-retina-display