# On iOS and iPhone, how to draw to a bitmap and display it in drawRect?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-graphics

It is said that for a single view app, it can be a programming choice to keep the current main view's content in a bitmap, and we paint extra things on this bitmap, and when it is time to do `drawRect` (when called by iOS), then we just display the bitmap.  (instead of redrawing 50,000 things every time `drawRect` is called. Just draw them once onto the bitmap instead).

Do somebody know exactly how to do it?  Exact code will be appreciated (probably requires code for 2 different files, one for `ViewController.m` and one for `MainView.m`), or can point to sample code snippet (nothing fancy please, just the simplest understandable code that can do this).  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [discussed in this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4334233/30461), you need to:

1. Create an image context.
2. Draw into it.
3. Get the image from it.
4. Pop it.