# Put UIView on UIButton and still have it highlight

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uibutton

In the past I've done the following:

```
thumbnailButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: thumbnailButtonFrame];
[thumbnailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(thumbnailButtonPushed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[thumbnailButton setBackgroundImage: thumbnailButtonImage forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[thumbnailButtonImage release];
```

Which has created a button that has a thumbnail image on it, and when pushed it sort of puts a grey highlight over it (much like the in the photos app when you're selecting a photo to display from the list of thumbnails).

I have a scenario now where I have a `UIView` class that draws a graphic in it's `drawRect` method. I'd like to put this `UIView` on the `UIButton` and have it highlight the same way if I add an image. I'd like to do this without subclassing `UIButton`. Is this possible?

Comment: y dont you use 2 images and set the images according to whether the button is selected or not selected??

Answer (score 3):

This should work. It may not be the exact method you are looking for however.

It involves converting a [UIView in UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334233/how-to-capture-uiview-to-uiimage-without-loss-of-quality-on-retina-display).

```
+ (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```

Then simply call this method in your code.

```
[thumbnailButton setBackgroundImage:[MyClass imageWithView:myCustomView] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

This may not give you your desired performance, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this approach.. You can have two images one for normal state and one for the highlighted state..

```
btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonInactiveImage.png"];
btnImageSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonActiveImage.png"];
btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: thumbnailButtonFrame];
btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setBackgroundImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // Set the image for the normal state of the button
[btn setBackgroundImage:btnImageSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected]; // Set the image for the selected state of the button
```

This way you don have to put any view on the button