# How to save the rotate image in iphone album?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, imagefilter

I am able to rotate the image when I click on view and image is rotating successfully but rotated image is not saving in iphone album.

When I click on save button previous image is saving in album please any one help me

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)_touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)_event
  {
   UITouch* touch = [_touches anyObject];
   CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:m_block];
   m_locationBegan = location;
   }

  - (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)_touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)_event
   {
    UITouch* touch = [_touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:m_block];
    [self updateRotation:location];  
   }

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)_touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)_event
    {
   UITouch *touch=[_touches anyObject];
   CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:m_block];
   m_currentAngle = [self updateRotation:location];    
 }
 - (float) updateRotation:(CGPoint)_location
   {
     float fromAngle = atan2(m_locationBegan.y-m_block.center.y, m_locationBegan.x-m_block.center.x);
    float toAngle = atan2(_location.y-m_block.center.y, _location.x-m_block.center.x);
     float newAngle = wrapd(m_currentAngle + (toAngle - fromAngle), 0, 2*3.14);

     CGAffineTransform cgaRotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(newAngle);
     m_block.transform = cgaRotate;
     int oneInFifty = (newAngle*50)/(2*3.14);
     m_label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Angle: %f 1in50: %i", newAngle, oneInFifty];
      return newAngle;
    }
  - (IBAction)saveImageToAlbum
     {
   [self.library saveImage:m_block.image toAlbum:@"My" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
      if (error!=nil) {
        NSLog(@"Big error: %@", [error description]);
    }
  }];

UIImage *image = m_block.image;
NSUserDefaults * user= [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] ;
[user setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) forKey:@"foo"];
[user synchronize];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using custom UIView Or UIImageView.

You can save current appearance of any View by following code:

```
+ (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```

I get this from : [How to capture UIView to UIImage without loss of quality on retina display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334233/how-to-capture-uiview-to-uiimage-without-loss-of-quality-on-retina-display)

This is working very well for me.

All the best...

Comment: i am getting the angle as you can see in my code then how to pass that angle in that image?

Comment: i have tried this code but its not working you can see in my code that i am retuning angle. that angle i have to save then how to do that please solve my problem..

Comment: Not working but what u r getting in image? blank image previous image? or any error

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_UIViewController._view", referenced from:
      -[ViewController captureView] in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: This is not code error this is build error. U can see "linker command failed"