# Replacing UISlider default thumb image with a multilayered image

Tags: ios, uislider

As far as I know there is no such thing as a multilayered image in iOS. If you want to display overlaid images you use UIImageViews.

If UISlider thumb was an image view it would have been easy to do, but since it's an UIImage is there a way to replace it with a multilayered image?

Comment: What is a multilayered image? Why not just flatten your "multilayered image" and use the flat version?

Comment: The image is created in real time and can change. Is there a way to create a flat image in code?

Comment: You first need to tell us what a "multilayered image" actually is. Why is it changing? You can render a UIView (and it's nested views) into a UIImage if that helps at all. You need to actually provide information though if you want any proper help.

Comment: In my case it is an image that is made up from a background image and on top of it a foreground image. These images can change according to the user's actions. Think of sliders that have certain images as thumbs that can change when the user changes theme.

Comment: Ah, I see, well depending on the number of options I'd do one of two things. Either create enough different single .png files so that all the themes are covered. Or alternately create your layered view with uiimageviews and then use this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334233/how-to-capture-uiview-to-uiimage-without-loss-of-quality-on-retina-display to render it into a single UIIMage object that can be used on the UISlider.