# Custom marker icon is blurry in Google Maps for iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm creating a GMSMarker by making a UIImage and then drawing some text on it:

```
 [(NSString*)text drawInRect:CGRectMake(scale*68, scale*4, scale*181, scale*49) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:12] lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
```

and adding it to my Google Maps map.  Everything looks great, except... the marker is blurry!  Specifically, the text on the marker (which should be sharp since I am not scaling the image in any way).  I'm using the latest GMS framework (04/2013).

I feel like this is a problem because when I do essentially the same thing using MapKit (Apple Map), the marker text is sharp.  Is anyone else seeing less-than-crisp marker icons?

It's almost as if Google is slightly downsampling or converting the image before overlaying it on the map...

Comment: Fixed.  Looks like it was me, not Google. [See this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334233/how-to-capture-uiview-to-uiimage-without-loss-of-quality-on-retina-display)