# How to save a transparent image with the subview below

Tags: ios

I have a ***transparent image*** and a UIView below and same size with the image. Everytime I want to change color of the image, I just set color to the UIView. My problem is how can I save the decorated image to the photo library? Since the color/decoration comes from the UIView below, not the image.

Thanks guy for reading.

Answer (score 1):

You can get screen shot of a view by this method:

```
+ (UIImage *) getScreenShot : (UIView *) view{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *screenImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return screenImage;
}
```

Pass your `baseView` in this method it'll return the decorated image.

Comment: It works but the image exported seems not in high quality. Do you know how to raise its quality?

Comment: I searched "draw hight resolution image UIGraphicsBeginImageContext" on google and found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334233/how-to-capture-uiview-to-uiimage-without-loss-of-quality-on-retina-display response