# set TintColor to MKAnnotationView image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I'm writing an application for `iOS 7.0+` and I wanted to use new feature witch is: `imageWithRenderingMode`. I have a map annotation with this code:

```
-(MKAnnotationView*)annotationView {
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:self reuseIdentifier:@"AnnotationIdentifier"];
    annotationView.enabled = YES;
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annotationView.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"star"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    annotationView.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return annotationView;
}
```

I was expected that my pins will be red, but stays black, only the callout (i) icon turns red.

[image]

I was trying to set `self.view.tintColor` and `self.mapView.tintColor` in my `ViewController` but this not working either. How to turns this pins red?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a better solution than those proposed that doesn't involve creating a `UIImageView`.

This Swift code will create a colored version of your `UIImage`.

```
extension UIImage {

    func colorized(color : UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0);
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetBlendMode(context, .Multiply)
        CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, self.CGImage)
        CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, self.CGImage)
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect)
        let colorizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return colorizedImage
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
UIImage(named: "myImage")!
    .imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
    .colorized(UIColor.red())
```

Comment: Thank you for this. My images were being drawn flipped, I added `CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.size.height); CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0)` before `CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, self.CGImage)` to fix that.

Comment: What is the blend mode about ? I had to remove it to get the correct color

Comment: @Vinzzz I believe which blend mode you use will depend on the color of your source image. In my case, I believe my images was white, but you can try other blend modes (even the default) to see how it affects your display.

Comment: swift 4 update : 'annotationView?.image = image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate).colorized(color: colour)'

Comment: Most people will probably want blend mode `.copy`, particularly when using system images

Answer (score 6):

I could make this work by [capturing an UIView to UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4334902/474671):

```
UIImage *pin = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pin.size.width, pin.size.height)];
imageView.image = [pin imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
imageView.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor]; // set the desired color

// now the magic...
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, imageView.opaque, 0.0);
[imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

annotationView.image = img;
```

Comment: Not working for me. `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` returns nil.

Answer (score 5):

Same as @sandy-chapman but in Swift 3. My images got flipped so I flip them back again.

```
extension UIImage {

  func colorized(color : UIColor) -> UIImage {

    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
    if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
        context.setBlendMode(.multiply)
        context.translateBy(x: 0, y: self.size.height)
        context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        context.draw(self.cgImage!, in: rect)
        context.clip(to: rect, mask: self.cgImage!)
        context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        context.fill(rect)
    }

    let colorizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return colorizedImage!

  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

How frustrating. I solved it like this (sans the other property configurations):

```
-(MKAnnotationView*)annotationView {
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation: self reuseIdentifier: @"AnnotationIdentifier"];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"star"] imageWithRenderingMode: UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
    UIImageView *screwYouApple = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
    screwYouApple.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [annotationView addSubview: screwYouApple];
    return annotationView;
}
```

Basically, I blow off the `image` property of the `annotationView` and use a properly tinted `UIImageView` as a `subview` of the annotation.

*Variable naming helped the experience be cathartic.*

Comment: Looks like this disables the call out.

Answer (score 4):

this works for me:

```swift
extension MKAnnotationView {
    
    public func set(image: UIImage, with color : UIColor) {
        let view = UIImageView(image: image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate))
        view.tintColor = color
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.isOpaque, 0.0)
        guard let graphicsContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        view.layer.render(in: graphicsContext)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        self.image = image
    }
        
}
```

(based on @Marcio Fonseca's answer)

---

edit: here's a small tweak to have both full color and tinted images:

```swift
extension MKAnnotationView {

    public func setPin(image: UIImage = UIImage(systemName: "mappin.circle.fill")!,
                       with color : UIColor? = nil) {
        let view: UIImageView
        
        if let color = color {
            // set tint color if specified
            view = UIImageView(image: image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate))
            view.tintColor = color
        } else {
            // keep original image colors if unspecified
            view = UIImageView(image: image)
        }
        
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.isOpaque, 0.0)
        guard let graphicsContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        view.layer.render(in: graphicsContext)
        
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        self.image = image
    }
}
```

here's how to call it:

```swift
// Use fallback pin image ("mappin.circle.fill") without tint
view.setPin()
// note: this will set it to black.
// you could change the default UIColor? value to .systemRed and pass nil in
// the rare case you might need to use an untinted app asset image

// Use fallback pin image with tint
view.setPin(with: .systemYellow)

// App assets image without tint
view.setPin(image: UIImage(named: "estech")!)

// App assets image with tint
view.setPin(image: UIImage(named: "estech")!, with: .systemBlue)
```

Answer (score 3):

Realize I'm very late to the game, however I was looking for the same thing as you, but found this useful.

Use `MKMarkerAnnotationView`, which has an attribute `markerTintColor`.

You won't get a custom pin image, but it will look a lot like the marker you had in your questions (see my attached image).

Here's a snippet of how I use it:

```
  // Somewhere else 
  mapView.register(MKMarkerAnnotationView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMarkerAnnotationView.self.description())  

  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        guard let companyAnnotation = annotation as? CompanyAnnotation else { return nil }
        let view = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: MKMarkerAnnotationView.self.description())
        view.markerTintColor = .colorFor(category: companyAnnotation.company.category)
        return view
   }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It does not appear that you are able to accomplish this at all using `tintColor`. `MKAnnotationView` does not use the tint color for image rendering like a `UIImageView` does. You'll need to either write some sort of method to draw a correctly colored image yourself, or provide an image with the color you want.

Comment: Ha , that strange since `MKAnnotationView image property` is regular `imageView`, but I pretty sure this is not possible, but can't figure out why...

Comment: `MKAnnotation` is a subclass of `UIView`, not `UIImageView`. And its `image` property is expecting an instance of `UIImage`.