# Taking a snapshot of view that isn't rendered?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiview, uiimage, screenshot

Say I have a view that isn't rendered, but I want to [convert it to a UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22494886/35690). It seems as though I cannot use [snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW198), since it says:

> If the current view is not yet rendered, perhaps because it is not yet onscreen, the snapshot view has no visible content.

How can I convert a UIView (e.g. a UILabel) into a UIImage without having to add it to the view hierarchy?

Here is the code I am using:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.text = @"Test";
[label sizeToFit];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(label.bounds.size, NO, 0.0f);
[label drawViewHierarchyInRect:label.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];
UIImage * snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This causes the snapshotImage to appear black, as one might expect. Is there an API similar to `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:` which will allow me to create the UIImage without requiring the view to be rendered?

Answer (score 1):

[renderInContext:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/renderInContext%3a), as far as I know, does not require the view to be rendered on screen:

```
[label.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```