# How to take screenshot with coretext programmatically

Tags: ios, uiview, nsattributedstring, core-text, uigraphicscontext

I am rendering a NSAttributedString using core text with clipping paths.I want to take the screen shot of coretext with out drawing it on a view.

I am going to take a screenshot in nsobject class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334233/how-to-capture-uiview-to-uiimage-without-loss-of-quality-on-retina-display

Comment: This is using UIView layer. Is it possible to do this without uiview. I just want to use CTFramesetterRef.