# Able to capture UIImage as-is based on content mode from UIimageView?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, crop

I was wondering if there is a way to capture an `UIImage` as it appears **as-is** viewed in an `UIImageView` based on its `contentMode`. For example, if I pass a `3:4` aspect ratio to a square `UIImageView`, and use "Aspect Fit" as the `contentMode`, then I'd expect to see white letterboxes in the left and right parts the image to fill out the square. Would it then be possible to take whatever appears and save it directly as an new `UIImage` with the letter boxing?

Thanks!

Comment: Try here, passing the imageview as the param: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334233/how-to-capture-uiview-to-uiimage-without-loss-of-quality-on-retina-display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture a "screen shot" of the way a UIImageView is actually displayed by calling CALayer's `renderInContext:` method.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/renderInContext: