# Email Sharing using UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using UIActivityViewController for email, facebook, twitter and sms sharing..

I have successfully shared image as well text.

But, now i want to share UIView. I wanted to know is it possible or not?

If yes please let me know how.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share `UIView`? What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a `UIImage` from a `UIView`,

Here is what you should be using if you are only supporting iOS7+:

```
+ (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0f);
    [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];
    UIImage * snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return snapshotImage;
}
```

Otherwise use this:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

+ (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```

Comment: Yoooooo....!!! Amazing... Thanks a lot...!!!! First solution of yours is working for me..

Comment: Great to hear that, be aware from the up porting iOS, the first one is for iOS7+

Answer (score 0):

You can take a screenshot of a `UIView` object. See please following topic:

[How to capture UIView to UIImage without loss of quality on retina display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334233/how-to-capture-uiview-to-uiimage-without-loss-of-quality-on-retina-display)

> I have successfully shared image as well text.

After getting `UIImage` from `UIView`, you can share appropriate image.