# How to put the camera preview into a UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, camera

I want to put the camera live view (back camera) inside the `ViewController` in `iOS` in `Swift` but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Add Live Camera Preview to UIView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487146/how-to-add-live-camera-preview-to-uiview)

Answer (score 1):

Please, search for answers first and if you do not found then come and ask. 
Here I am giving some which I found it here only. you can get more.

[How to Add Live Camera Preview to UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487146/how-to-add-live-camera-preview-to-uiview)

[Take photos with live video preview using AVFoundation](http://red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/ios4-take-photos-with-live-video-preview-using-avfoundation/)

Comment: if this works for you, accept the answer as well. Thanks