# How to show camera in UIView and capture images from that camera in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How we can show camera in UIView and capture images from that camera. How is it possible in iOS. I have seen for video preview but I need only to capture images from my view. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For that you can use the http://red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/ios4-take-photos-with-live-video-preview-using-avfoundation/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487146/how-to-add-live-camera-preview-to-uiview

Comment: always check apple documentation, sample code and google before asking in SO

Comment: @Bluewings - I have already checked that AVCam from Apple documentation and I am getting errors from that apple's example source code.

Comment: let us know what error you get from AVCam sample code base. We can try to help you with that