# Animation when tab changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, tabs

I want to change to another tab  but i also want to open it from bottom. Like a vertical transition.

I was trying to do like this :

```
  -(void)test{

    UIView * toView = [[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] view];


    UIImage *img=[self imageWithView:toView];



    [UIView transitionWithView:img
                      duration:1.0f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                    animations:^{
                        self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
                    } completion:NULL];



}

- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
    return false;
}
- (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();







    return img;
}
```

but it's not the effect that i want . Any ideea?

Comment: so when you select the tab, you want to present view controller from the bottom ?

Comment: yes, this is what i want

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

Firstly. return `false` in the UITabBarController' delegate. So the system won't change the tab immediately when user selecting the tab.
`- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController`

Secondly. [Capture your toView to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334233/how-to-capture-uiview-to-uiimage-without-loss-of-quality-on-retina-display)

Thirdly. Do any animation you want with the imageView.

Finally. Set `selectedIndex` of your tabBarController and remove the imageView when the animation completed.

Feel free to ask me. Thanks!

Comment: @AdinaMarin Add the image to UIWindow with a origin frame(maybe outside of the screen). then do the animation that moving the image to the view frame.