# Adding rotation to UIImage in the ImageView- not the ImageView in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, rotation, uiimage

I am trying to add a user interactive rotation option to iOS app. I don't want to rotate the imageView but want to rotate the UIImage displayed on the imageView. I know how to do it on the imageView.

It is important to add the procedure through which image is provided to the imageView. I first take the image from Camera or Photo Library. Then, I crop the image using a crop tool created. I have followed the following code for the crop:

> https://github.com/johnomarkid/BFCropInterface

After the crop I want to rotate the image like Photos Edit option in iPhone. Can anyone help in this regard?

Comment: Do you want to rotate by 90 degrees? Or just to any angle. Apple iPhone native app allow you rotate to any angle.

Comment: I want to rotate the UIImage after cropping to any angle! If native app supports, how can it be implemented?

Comment: I guess first you have to rotate uiimageview using CGAffineTransformRotate after that you have to render uiimageview to image. I haven't done anything I am just giving you idea

Comment: How is it possible to render uiimageview to image?

Comment: Check this link how uiview can be render into uiimage http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334233/how-to-capture-uiview-to-uiimage-without-loss-of-quality-on-retina-display if you find difficulty then put uiimageview to uiview then render uiview to uiimage after rotating uiimageview.

Comment: Alright! I will give it a shot and let you know. Is there any framework you are aware of that can do such job?

Comment: Tomorrow I will check in office will try to implement this feature. I will let you know.