# How to I start at a different coordinate than (0, 0) in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to take a screenshot that is 375x375 pixels wide, but I don't want it to start at (0, 0) in the top left of the screen, I want it to start at (0, 64). How can I accomplish this?

Here is my function:

```
func screenShotMethod() {
    let size = CGSize(width: 375, height: 375)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions((size), false, 0.0)
    view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image!, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

Comment: You can take size(375, 375+64) and crop rect(0, 64, 375, 375). [Crop Image](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7704399/6279975)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way that you can do it is creating a `UIView` with the same size that you want and make its background to be clear color and then use that `UIView` instead of the `view` in your code.

You can also use the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39299100/1450348) which is an extension for `UIView` and does exactly what you want to do