# Swift: How to take a screenshot of the screen under a view

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

So here's some background. I have some `UICollectionViewCell` that have transparent backgrounds, but I still want them to have shadows, which don't really render as expected (around the view, instead of around each opaque subview\element in it) so I was thinking of taking a screenshot over the parent view and setting that as a background image to get "fake" the view being transparent. What would be the best way to do that?

Essentially:

1. Get a screenshot of the screen *below* a `UICollectionViewCell`
2. Clip the screenshot to the frame/bounds of the cell

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39283807/how-to-take-screenshot-of-portion-of-uiview) post, but I doesn't seem to work for whatever reason. `drawHierarchy` keeps returning false. I'm also assuming it gets the entire view hierarchy, not the views below the one requested it

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: Nope, and I'm not sure what the issue is

Comment: I think I might help you on this stuff, but first you should clarify couple of things, like: "that have transparent backgrounds, but I still want them to have shadows" what you mean? Might you post an example of what you want to achieve?