# Capture uiview as an image

Tags: ios, image, uiview, gif

I have a UIView that contains some labels and other data with the gif image.I want to capture that view as an image in a way that my gif animation remains intact in captured image

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4334902/5902078

Comment: What code are you using to display the animated GIF to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

I think below code will help you to capture your entire view and return as uiimage :

```
   -(UIImage*)captureView:(UIView*)myView
    {
        UIImage *screengrab;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(myView.bounds.size, myView.opaque, 0.0);
        [myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        screengrab = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return screengrab;
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this method and it captures the view layer as image but i want to keep gif(which is added as subview in view) animated after capturing the view as image or anything else to obtain this functionality

Comment: do you mean that captured image i.e. "screengrab" image need to have 'animating' action gif image in it??

Comment: Yes,the captured image(screengrab) need to have 'animating' gif image in it.I really appreciate your help.Thanks

Comment: bro.. i doubt this !! it may be possible !? there won't be simple answer.

Comment: I have tried this method and it captures the view layer as image but i want to keep gif(which is added as subview in view) animated after capturing the view as image or anything else to obtain this functionality @Ashish Shah