# Views drawn from code (PaintCode) are pixelated, very pixelated when scaled

Tags: ios, swift, paintcode

I am building an app that overlays views drawn with code (output from PaintCode) onto photos. I have added gesture recognizers to rotate and scale the views drawn with code.

There is some mild pixelation on the views drawn on top. If I do any rotation or scale the image larger (even a slight bit), there is a lot more pixelation.

Here is a comparison of the images:

No rotating or scaling:
[image: No rotation or scaling]

A small amount of rotation/scaling:
[image: A small amount of rotation/scaling]

Here is the UIView extension I'm using to output the composited view:

```
extension UIView {

    func printViewToImage() -> UIImage {
        let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
        format.scale = 2.0

        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: self.bounds, format: format)
        return renderer.image { rendererContext in
            self.drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Even if I set the scale to something like 4.0, there is no difference.

Here is the code I'm using for the scale/rotation gesture recognizers:

```
@IBAction func handlePinch(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let view = recognizer.view else {
        return
    }

    view.transform = view.transform.scaledBy(x: recognizer.scale, y: recognizer.scale)
    recognizer.scale = 1
}

@IBAction func handleRotate(recognizer: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let view = recognizer.view else {
        return
    }

    view.transform = view.transform.rotated(by: recognizer.rotation)
    recognizer.rotation = 0
}
```

I have experimented with making the canvasses very large in PaintCode (3000x3000), and there is no difference, so I don't think it has to do with that.

**How can I draw/export these views so that they are not pixelated?**

*Edit: Here's what some of the drawing code looks like...*

```
public dynamic class func drawCelebrateDiversity(frame targetFrame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 3000, height: 3000), resizing: ResizingBehavior = .aspectFit, color: UIColor = UIColor(red: 1.000, green: 1.000, blue: 1.000, alpha: 1.000)) {
    //// General Declarations
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    //// Resize to Target Frame
    context.saveGState()
    let resizedFrame: CGRect = resizing.apply(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 3000, height: 3000), target: targetFrame)
    context.translateBy(x: resizedFrame.minX, y: resizedFrame.minY)
    context.scaleBy(x: resizedFrame.width / 3000, y: resizedFrame.height / 3000)


    //// Bezier 13 Drawing
    let bezier13Path = UIBezierPath()
    bezier13Path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 2915.18, y: 2146.51))
    bezier13Path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 2925.95, y: 2152.38), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 2919.93, y: 2147.45), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 2924.05, y: 2147.91))
```

Comment: Is there an approach with PaintCode that would allow you to avoid rasterization entirely?

Comment: Hey, just a short question, as you have a static scale defined (set to 2). Do you take the [UIScreen mainScreen].scale into consideration for this? I think your raster does not fit to the retina resolution? Just a rough guess, tho.

Comment: @ChrisDroukas As I understand it, PaintCode uses coordinates for drawing, but is not rasterized. Adding a bit of a drawing function above...

Comment: @Lepidopteron If I set the scale to 4.0, for example, the output is larger, but the pixelation looks the same.

Comment: You need to scale the bounds of your UIGraphicsImageRenderer. Probably times the screen scale

Comment: Have you tried to rasterize the view's layer? view.layer.shouldRasterize = true

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks for the reply. In the beginning of the UIView extension, I am creating the UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat, setting that scale to 2, and passing that into the renderer. I just tried setting the scale to 6, and the pixelation is the same. Is there a different way to scale the bounds of the UIGraphicsImageRenderer?

Comment: @Lepidopteron Thanks, I tried that (setting it in viewDidLoad), but the results are not less pixelated.

Comment: Do you use somewhere "UIGraphicsBeginImageContext* instead of "UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions" with correct options? Because this would result in a scale factor of 1 instead of the factor being adjusted to the scale of the display. Have a detailed look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334233/how-to-capture-uiview-to-uiimage-without-loss-of-quality-on-retina-display

Comment: @Lepidopteron I just searched in the project, and I am not using UIGraphicsBeginImageContext anywhere.

Comment: The pixelation is visible in live views or only after creating the image? Do you use drawing method or image method from PaintCode? Are you using `shouldRasterize` on any of those views?

Comment: And just an obvious check: Is the overlay created in PaintCode using image or using bezier paths?

Comment: @Tricertops The overlay is created using bezier paths (the drawing methods from the PaintCode output, not images). I am not calling shouldRasterize, should I be calling it on any of them?

Comment: @aaronfalls No, don’t enable rasterization, but it has it’s own rasterizationScale that could be set wrong. I think I know what’s the issue, I’m going to write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When scaling UIViews (or custom CALayers), you should set their `contentsScale` to match the desired density of their content. UIViews set their layer `contentsScale` to screen scale (2 on retina), and you need to multiply this with the extra scale you do via transform.

```
view.layer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale * gesture.scale;
```

Even if the drawing code is resolution independent, everything on screen must be converted to bitmap at some time. UIView allocates bitmap with size of `bounds.size * contentsScale` and then invokes `-drawRect:`/`draw(_ rect:)` method.

It is important to set `contentsScale` on that view that draws, even if that view is not scaled (but some of its parent is). A common solution is to recursively set `contentsScale` on all sublayers of the scaled view.

<sub>– PaintCode Support</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the reply! For some reason, `view.layer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale * recognizer.scale` did not work for me in the gesture recognizer function. Based on your explanation, I experimented a bit, and `view.contentScaleFactor = view.contentScaleFactor * recognizer.scale` works perfectly—crisp no matter how scaled it is. I had also tried using `view.contentScaleFactor = UIScreen.main.scale * recognizer.scale`, but that did not work.

Comment: @aaronfalls That’s probably because you reset the scale value after every change using `recognizer.scale = 1`. I wouldn’t do that.