# How to convert UIView to UIImage with high resolution?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimage

There have been several discussions regarding how to convert UIView to UIImage, either using `view.drawHierarchy(in:)` or `view.layer.renderInContext()`. However, even if set the scale to device scale, the result is still in pretty bad resolution. I wonder if there's a way to transform a UIView to UIImage with high resolution and quality?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to capture UIView to UIImage without loss of quality on retina display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334233/how-to-capture-uiview-to-uiimage-without-loss-of-quality-on-retina-display)

Comment: Thanks, but that is still using the above 2 methods, and the result is still not good :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the correct content scale on each subview.

```
extension UIView {   
    func scale(by scale: CGFloat) {
        self.contentScaleFactor = scale        
        for subview in self.subviews {
            subview.scale(by: scale)
        }
    }

    func getImage(scale: CGFloat? = nil) -> UIImage {
        let newScale = scale ?? UIScreen.main.scale
        self.scale(by: newScale)

        let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
        format.scale = newScale

        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: self.bounds.size, format: format)

        let image = renderer.image { rendererContext in            
            self.layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
        }

        return image
    }
}
```

To create your image:

```
let image = yourView.getImage()
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the well-detailed explanation and usage!

Comment: I tried this solution but it doesn't work? How did you manage to do it?