# How to render UIView into an image at higher resolution?

Tags: swift, uiview, calayer, snapshot

I'm trying to create image-snapshot tests for `UIView`. Unfortunately for me my CI machines have @1x pixel-to-point ratio, and my local machine has @2x, so basically I'm trying to render a `UIView` on @1x machine as it would look on @2x machine.

My code looks like this:

```
let contentsScale = 2

view.contentScaleFactor = contentsScale
view.layer.contentsScale = contentsScale

let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
format.scale = contentsScale
        
let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: bounds.size, format: format)
let image = renderer.image { ctx in
    self.drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
}
```

So problem is that when it reaches `CALayer.draw(in ctx: CGContext)` inside of `drawHierarchy`, the `view.contentScaleFactor` and `view.layer.contentsScale` are back to 1 (or whatever `UIScreen.main.scale` is). It happens in this callstack:

```
* MyUIView.contentScaleFactor
* _UIDrawViewRectAfterCommit
* closure #1 in convertViewToImage
```

I also noticed that there is `; _moveViewToTemporaryWindow` in assembly code of `_UIDrawViewRectAfterCommit` call, which I guess it means it attaches my view to some temporary window which resets the scale. I tried changing the scale again in `didMoveToWindow`, i.e. right before the drawing, but the view comes out as pixelated even if `view.contentScaleFactor` is correct in the rendering of of the layer.

I noticed that some people try to solve it with using scaling on `CGContext`, but it makes no sense as the underlying quality is not scaled.

So what am I missing? How do render `UIView` into an image using desired scale?

Comment: This may work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51944513/6257435 -- quick test, using a view with a subview, which contains a label as its subview ... seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I did several things to get this working:

- Render layer instead of the view itself (`view.layer.render(in: ctx.cgContext)` as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51944513/6257435
- Views should have a size that is multiple of your `contentsScale` otherwise you get weird antialiasing and interpolation issues on the lines.
- Avoid transforms that have odd scales (like `1.00078...` in my case) otherwise you get weird antialiasing and interpolation issues on the lines.
- I'm using `format.preferredRange = .standard` color range to make it work the same locally and on CI too.