# How to render snapshot in higher resolution?

Tags: swift, swiftui, snapshot

I'm using a custom package from [RickeyBoy](https://github.com/RickeyBoy/ScreenshotableView). It's a view in SwiftUI that supports custom screenshot functionality. This solution is just what I need for my current project, but the problem is that it's making snapshots in low resolution. I've tried increasing it by 10 in `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`, but it's still looked bad. In my previous project I've used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44511202/how-to-convert-uiview-to-uiimage-with-high-resolution/51944513#51944513). You can see here that I can increase the rendering resolution by passing the CGFloat. And that's it. But when I'm doing it here: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, self.isOpaque, 10)`, it's still bad. What can I do to fix it? Thank you in advance.

```
// ScreenshotableView
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

public enum SVStyle {
    /// 截图中的样式
    /// style in screenshot image
    case inScreenshot
    /// 正常展现的样式
    /// style in normally displayed View
    case inView
}

public struct SV<Content: View>: View {
    @Binding var shotting: Bool
    var completed: (UIImage) -> Void
    let content: (_ style: SVStyle) -> Content
    
    public init(shotting:Binding<Bool>, completed: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (_ style: SVStyle) -> Content) {
        self._shotting = shotting
        self.completed = completed
        self.content = content
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        
        func internalView(proxy: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
            if self.shotting {
                let frame = proxy.frame(in: .global)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    shotting = false
                    // 截图时用 inSnapshot 的样式
                    // Use content with '.inScreenshot' style while taking a screenshot
                    let screenshot = self.content(.inView).takeScreenshot(frame: frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
                    self.completed(screenshot)
                }
            }
            return Color.clear
        }
        
        // 展示 inView style 的内容
        // Display content with 'inView' style
        return content(.inView).background(GeometryReader(content: internalView(proxy:)))
    }
}
```

```
// SV Extensions
import SwiftUI

extension UIView {
    
    func takeScreenshot() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, self.isOpaque, 10)
        self.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let capturedImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return capturedImage
    }
    
    func takeScreenshot(afterScreenUpdates: Bool) -> UIImage {
        if !self.responds(to: #selector(drawHierarchy(in:afterScreenUpdates:))) {
            return self.takeScreenshot()
        }
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, self.isOpaque, 10)
        self.drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: afterScreenUpdates)
        let snapshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return snapshot!
    }
}

extension View {
    func takeScreenshot(frame:CGRect, afterScreenUpdates: Bool) -> UIImage {
        let hosting = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        hosting.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIApplication.shared.currentUIWindow()?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle ?? .unspecified
        hosting.view.frame = frame
        return hosting.view.takeScreenshot(afterScreenUpdates: afterScreenUpdates)
    }
}

extension UIApplication {
    func currentUIWindow() -> UIWindow? {
        let connectedScenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
            .filter { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }
            .compactMap { $0 as? UIWindowScene }
        
        let window = connectedScenes.first?
            .windows
            .first { $0.isKeyWindow }

        return window
    }
}
```