# Objective-C: how to get zoomed content of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView which displays UIView with UIImageView a subview.
Zooming works great, everything is nice an sharp. I need to do some action on zoomed content (show it in another view). 
How I can get zoomed content of UIView, meaning content which was processed by UIScrollView zoom routines ? Even when zoomed my UIView content is the same (not zoomed).

Answer (score 0):

Michal - Welcome to StackOverflow.

This answer ( [How to capture UIView to UIImage without loss of quality on retina display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334233/how-to-capture-uiview-to-uiimage-without-loss-of-quality-on-retina-display) ) does a good job of showing how to create an image from a view.

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to create an image from the `UIScrollView`, and that image would correctly reflect the zoom and clipping done by the `UIScrollView`.

Comment: Yes, in general this is correct approach. But for some reason when I check UIScrollView the zoomed content is not updated even if actual view shows it OK.