# custom google map marker icon image in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-markers

I am converting custom view load from xib into `UIImage` to show as  a marker icon.it is done but the problem is to when doing this in for loop to show 100 markers UI get stuck is it because of loading xib custom view?

below is the function calling  in for loop

```
func generateSpot(Prop: Property) -> Spot {

    let latStr = Prop.propLat
    let langStr = Prop.propLang as NSString
    let langDbl : Double = Double(langStr.floatValue)
    let latDbl : Double  = Double(latStr.floatValue)

    let marker:GMSMarker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(langDbl,latDbl)
    marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
    marker.title = Prop.propBuildingName as String
    marker.snippet = Prop.propCode as String
    marker.infoWindowAnchor = CGPointMake(0.44, 0.45)

    let sizeVar:CGSize = CGSize(width: 41, height: 37)

    let customeMarker :CustomMarker = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self.view, options: nil).first! as! CustomMarker

    customeMarker.frame = CGRectMake(customeMarker.frame.minX,customeMarker.frame.minY,customeMarker.frame.width,customeMarker.frame.height)
    customeMarker.mappedNumbers.layer.masksToBounds = true
    customeMarker.mappedNumbers.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    customeMarker.mappedNumbers.text = Prop.propSequence as String

    if Prop.propStatus == self.constants!.status.STATUS_COMPLETED_XML
    {
        customeMarker.mappedNumbers.backgroundColor = self.utility!.uicolorFromHex(0x70b420)
        customeMarker.arrowImage.tintColor = self.utility!.uicolorFromHex(0x70b420)
    }

    if Prop.propStatus == self.constants!.status.STATUS_DRAFT_XML
    {
        customeMarker.mappedNumbers.backgroundColor = self.utility!.uicolorFromHex(0xd2cb46)
        customeMarker.arrowImage.tintColor = self.utility!.uicolorFromHex(0x70b420)


    }
    if Prop.propStatus == self.constants!.status.STATUS_PENDING_XML
    {
        customeMarker.mappedNumbers.backgroundColor = self.utility!.uicolorFromHex(0xd44646)
        customeMarker.arrowImage.tintColor = self.utility!.uicolorFromHex(0xd44646)


    }


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sizeVar, false, 0)
    customeMarker.drawViewHierarchyInRect(customeMarker.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    marker.icon = newImage
    marker.map = self.googleMapView
    let spotObje:Spot = Spot()
    spotObje.location = marker.position
    spotObje.marker = marker
    return spotObje
}
```

Comment: do it in a background thread

Comment: tried in background thread but error comes   This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.

Comment: please show updated code in a separate http://gist.github.com link

Comment: https://gist.github.com/nitisha1/0763585550ed6be1cfa931408232f180

Comment: is this code loading things on bg thread ? to me looks like everything being done on main thread ?

Comment: sorry ,updated check again

Comment: okay i checked. can you put breakpoints and see on which line it shows the autolayout error. there are several things going on it like marker frame manipulation, layer etc so not sure which UI part is throwing error

Comment: loading xib in background  thread only no marker do but  still unable to interect with UI as freely like i possible in android or is there any concept of handlers passing message after process completion like android in swift?

Answer (score 0):

solved
replaced

```
 customeMarker.drawViewHierarchyInRect(customeMarker.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
```

with

```
customeMarker.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
```

Reference :  [drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates: delays other animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23157653/drawviewhierarchyinrectafterscreenupdates-delays-other-animations)